# Would it be better to use Serialized/Deserialize or Lists for generalized Set creation?

Tags: apex, set, collection, serialization, casting

As a Salesforce developer, I find I frequently need to extract Sets from `List<SObject>`, so I'm looking to create a generalized way of creating Sets.

The problem is, Salesforce thinks `Set<Object>` is never an instance of `Set<Id>`, `Set<String>`, etc.

I've created this helper class:

```
    private class SetExtractor {
        SObjectField extractedField;
        XAP_PRED_SObjectPredicateIntf predicate;

        SetExtractor(SObjectField extractedField, XAP_PRED_SObjectPredicateIntf predicate) {
            this.extractedField = extractedField;
            this.predicate = predicate;
        }

        SetExtractor(SObjectField extractedField) {
            this(extractedField, new XAP_PRED_SObjectFieldHasNonBlankValue(extractedField) 
        }

        public Set<Object> extractFrom(List<SObject> sObjectList) {
            Set<Object> resultSet = new Set<Object>();
            for (SObject sObj : sObjectList) {
                if (this.predicate.isTrueFor(sObj)) {
                    resultSet.add(sObj.get(extractionField));
                }
            }
            return resultSet;
        }
    }
```

This is the Predicate interface:

```
public interface XAP_PRED_SObjectPredicateIntf {
    Boolean isTrueFor(SObject sObj);
}
```

I can solve the problem of converting from `Set<Object>` to `Set<Id>` using serialize/deserialize, for example:

```
public virtual Set<Id> extractNonNullIdsFrom(List<SObject> sObjectList, SObjectField idField) {
    Set<Object> objectSet = new SetExtractor(idField)
            .extractFrom(sObjectList);
    return (Set<Id>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(objectSet), Set<Id>.class);
}
```

But it is my understanding that serialize/deserialize are expensive operations.

Alternatively, instead of initially extracting a Set, I could extract a List, i.e.:

```
public virtual Set<Id> extractNonNullIdsFrom(List<SObject> sObjectList, SObjectField idField) {
    List<Object> objectList = new ListForSetExtractor(idField)
            .extractFrom(sObjectList);
    return new Set<Id>((List<Id>)objectList);
}
```

- I'm wondering if there is a downside to this later approach?
- Would the size of either the source sObjectList or the result objectList matter?
- If so, what might be a good way to determine the tipping point?

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use [Map Constructor](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_map.htm#apex_System_Map_ctor)?  and then use the keySet to get Set?

```
Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(sObjectList)).keySet();
```

Comment: Good question... Let me share more code to make it more clear what I am doing.  :-)

Comment: I've added some code.  By the way, you'll notice that here I'm not just getting the keySet, but possibly any Ids contained in the SObject.  Or, more abstractly, I could get any set of values which meets the predicate criteria.